# Thrift client on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, thrift

I'm new to android development and want to create an app with a thrift client which is using a thrift server on my network. I already got the thrift definition file and the java code generated by the thrift compiler.

1. How do I need to start? How do I add the thrift library to my project? Do I need to compile it myself and if yes how should I accomplish this to be android compatible?
2. Can I directly use the auto generated functions similar to this

   ```
   public void getProduct(int productID, org.apache.thrift.async.AsyncMethodCallback resultHandler)
   ```

   to make asynchronous calls to my service so that I follow the android best practices? Or does using this function block my application in any way or is there another way to be preferred over this on android?

I use the current version of googles ADT (eclipse). My app needs to run just on android 4+ devices (I set the minSdkVersion to `15`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. yes, you need to build the thrift-lib for Android by yourself. Android has it's own httpcore that doesn't have a consume-method. here you can find how to change the thrift-library: [here instruction](http://grokbase.com/t/thrift/commits/12cpyd071g/git-commit-thrift-1641-thrift-0-8-not-compatible-with-android-httpclient-patch-darin-tay)
   After that just add the jar-file to the libs-folder and add it to the build-path.
2. example

   ```
   THttpClient hclient = new THttpClient("your/endpoint/url");
   TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(hclient); // it depends on your data-format
   Service.Client client = new Service.Client(protocol);
   Product product = client.getProduct(int productID);
   ```

you need to execute it as an Android AsyncTask: [AsyncTask | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 9):

Sorry to pile on to an old question.  As of February 2016, there is an Android-specific Thrift compiler and client: https://github.com/Microsoft/thrifty.

The classes that it generates use as few methods as possible (much smaller than the Apache implementation), and the generated clients are asynchronous by default.

Comment: Thrifty is cool, but lacks a critical feature:  being able to deserialize a known Thrift object from a byte array -- equivalent to TDeserializer in Apache Thrift.  The upshot is that if you have your own RPC system, you can't use Thrifty.

Comment: While there is no direct analog of TDeserializer, you can approximate it with each type's built-in Adapter.  The missing piece (an abstract way to get said adapter) has been added since version 0.3.0.  Our use of Thrifty is, in fact, with a custom RPC system.  We had to do some scaffolding, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: That is amazing news.  Thank you.  I'll try it out ASAP.