# How to integrate thrift module with react native?

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, thrift

Im using react-native (on Linux) to create some android application which has a client-server protocol. This client-server protocol was made with Thrift.

The problem is **react-native doesn't run on nodejs environment** and Thrifit libs use native nodejs modules so much, like util, net, events, tls, child_process, http, https and so on. I tried install each of those modules with npm install, but doesn't work for all of them.

Is there another way to install all native nodejs modules to my react-native application? Someone know how to use thrift and react-native ?

Comment: I'd suggest to ask that question on the mailing list as well..

Answer (score 0):

The Thrift libs you are speaking of are the NodeJS Thrift libs.

Thrift has libraries in other Languages like Java, Python, C++, etc.

To get Thrift running on React Native Android, I suggest you:

1. [Build the Android thrift libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141177/thrift-client-on-android#19930711).
2. Verify your Thrift Client is working in native Android code.
3. Create a React Native [Native Module](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content) (Java bridge class).
4. Call your Native Module from React Native Javascript code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there anyway to make it work on ReactNative side with javascript? React supports Websockets and some other stuff. Would it be possible to use them to make it all work on React Native side without doing them natively?